# Regular expression in Python Tree

Tags: python, regex

```
(ROOT
(S
(INTJ (UH Hello))
(, ,)
(NP (PRP$ My) (NN name))
(VP (VBZ is) (ADJP (JJ Melroy)))
(. .)))
(ROOT
(SBARQ
(WHNP (WP What))
(SQ (VBZ is) (NP (PRP$ your) (NN name)))
(. ?)))
```

I have many of these string available in python.Actually its a tree representation. I want to extract parent and child node for every word. Eg for word `hello` I want `(INTJ, UH)`. Similarly for word `My` it is `(NP, PRP$)`.

This is the outcome I want:

```
(INTJ, UH) , (NP, PRP$), (NP, NN) , (VP, VBZ) , (VP , VPZ) , (ADJP, JJ) , (WHNP, WP), (SQ, VBZ), (NP, PRP$), (NP, NN)
```

Any suggestion or hint into how to do it.?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code that outputs what you want.

In this code, I check line by line for something like (BLAH (BLIH BLOH)), I remove (BLIH BLOH) and keep iterating until no match is found.

```
astr = '''(ROOT
(S
(INTJ (UH Hello))
(, ,)
(NP (PRP$ My) (NN name))
(VP (VBZ is) (ADJP (JJ Melroy)))
(. .)))
(ROOT
(SBARQ
(WHNP (WP What))
(SQ (VBZ is) (NP (PRP$ your) (NN name)))
(. ?)))'''


def get_tree(astr):
    import re
    out = []
    lines = astr.splitlines()

    for line in lines:
        pat = '\(([^\(\)]+?)( \(([^\)\(]+?) [^\(\)]+?\)).*?\)'
        res = re.search(pat, line)
        while res:
            out.append((res.group(1), res.group(3)))
            line = line.replace(res.group(2),'')
            # line = re.sub('(\([^\s\(\)]*\))', '', line)
            res = re.search(pat, line)

    return out

get_tree(aster) # returns [('INTJ', 'UH'), ('NP', 'PRP$'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('VP', 'VBZ'), ('ADJP', 'JJ'), ('WHNP', 'WP'), ('SQ', 'VBZ'), ('NP', 'PRP$'), ('NP', 'NN')]
```